# Application is failing on iPad Air 2 running iOS 9.2.1 and works on all other devices

Tags: ios, swift, ipad

I have been struggling to figure out the problem I am have with my application. I have submitted it to apple and it has been rejected with the saying "2.10 Details
Your app crashed when reviewed on iPad running iOS 9.2.1 when we:
- Launch on launch". The app works on my iPad 3rd generation, all the simulators, and my iPhone 6. When I asked what device it was crashing on, they said it was the iPad Air 2. Unfortunately, I don't own an iPad Air 2 and have no other way to get the same results. Here are the things I have tried to solve the problem:

- I deleted the "Supported interface orientations (iPad)" from my .plist - nothing changed
- I created a new scheme that tested the app in release mode in the simulator - no errors
- I tried symbolicating the crash report but I have yet to produce anything from that..it's possible I could be doing it wrong.

I have posted the crash report below and the error seems to be EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP). To my understanding this is an error that relates to a non-optional type with a nil value or a failed force type conversion. If that is the case, why would other devices not experience the same error when they launch? Does the iPad Air 2 do something different at launch that I am not aware of. My only guess at this point is that it has something to do with my build settings. I only included the first few binary images because I don't have space in this post.

```
Incident Identifier: 2AFC52E4-1A97-4EAE-8E4B-E0ACE1A72E0F
CrashReporter Key:   3468d98e3e8b6cebaa2f0ba50993f8d4768ac7cc
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:             WeatherIt [1458]
Path:                              /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/710543EA-CD06-4A04-8D8D-       3214C0C5C4F6/WeatherIt.app/WeatherIt
Identifier:          com.buessing.myWeather
Version:             1 (0.9.1)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2016-02-09 12:41:12.12 -0800
Launch Time:         2016-02-09 12:41:11.11 -0800
OS Version:          iOS 9.2.1 (13D15)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00000001000d5e50
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Global Trace Buffer (reverse chronological seconds):
1.179051     AppleJPEG                  0x0000000185ece338 [0x15e858200]   Created session



Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   WeatherIt                       0x00000001000d5e50 0x1000bc000 + 106064
1   WeatherIt                       0x00000001000d5e70 0x1000bc000 + 106096
2   Foundation                      0x000000018522ce2c 0x185138000 + 1003052
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001848215f4 0x184744000 + 906740
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184821298 0x184744000 + 905880
5   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018481e9ac 0x184744000 + 895404
6   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018474d680 0x184744000 + 38528
7   GraphicsServices                0x0000000185c5c088 0x185c50000 + 49288
8   UIKit                           0x00000001895c4d90 0x189548000 + 511376
9   WeatherIt                       0x00000001000dc7e4 0x1000bc000 + 133092
10  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001842ee8b8 0x1842ec000 + 10424

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018440d4fc 0x1843f0000 + 120060
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001842d094c 0x1842bc000 + 84300
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001842bf7bc 0x1842bc000 + 14268

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018440cb6c 0x1843f0000 + 117612
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001844d1530 0x1844d0000 + 5424
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001844d1020 0x1844d0000 + 4128

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018440cb6c 0x1843f0000 + 117612
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001844d1530 0x1844d0000 + 5424
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001844d1020 0x1844d0000 + 4128

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018440cb6c 0x1843f0000 + 117612
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001844d1530 0x1844d0000 + 5424
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001844d1020 0x1844d0000 + 4128

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018440cb6c 0x1843f0000 + 117612
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001844d1530 0x1844d0000 + 5424
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001844d1020 0x1844d0000 + 4128

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0xa00cc08054081658   x1: 0x0000000000000001   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000003
    x4: 0x0000000000000000   x5: 0x0000000000000000   x6: 0xa000000363130324   x7: 0x0000000000000000
    x8: 0x0000000000000001   x9: 0x0000000000000005  x10: 0x00000001849f3954  x11: 0x0000000000000000
   x12: 0x0000000000000046  x13: 0x0000000000000000  x14: 0x000000008000001f  x15: 0x0000000080000023
   x16: 0x00000001003ef9b4  x17: 0x0000000184850c7c  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000001
   x20: 0x000000015d72ebd0  x21: 0x000000015d5de230  x22: 0x000000015d5c4b30  x23: 0x000000015d877e00
   x24: 0x0000000000000000  x25: 0xa00cc08054081658  x26: 0x00000001004422a0  x27: 0x000000015d72fb60
   x28: 0x8800c5a414ba66f3  fp: 0x000000016fd41b80   lr: 0x00000001000d5b4c
    sp: 0x000000016fd41a00   pc: 0x00000001000d5e50 cpsr: 0xa0000000

Binary Images:
0x1000bc000 - 0x1000e3fff WeatherIt arm64  <0f5c7fd68c92311496ed8e1c1f347435> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/710543EA-CD06-4A04-8D8D-3214C0C5C4F6/WeatherIt.app/WeatherIt
0x100114000 - 0x10016bfff Alamofire arm64  <992c3b1d65933b05b5f335aa58b98179> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/710543EA-CD06-4A04-8D8D-3214C0C5C4F6/WeatherIt.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire
0x1001b8000 - 0x1001c7fff MBProgressHUD arm64  <ba2397e352a131a2bbc41f02452766e5> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/710543EA-CD06-4A04-8D8D-3214C0C5C4F6/WeatherIt.app/Frameworks/MBProgressHUD.framework/MBProgressHUD
0x1001e0000 - 0x1001e7fff libswiftContacts.dylib arm64  <db9dd499b19a3b639a920a0d71868944> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/710543EA-CD06-4A04-8D8D-3214C0C5C4F6/WeatherIt.app/Frameworks/libswiftContacts.dylib
0x1001f8000 - 0x100413fff libswiftCore.dylib arm64  <ba84e1c7148f37b0b36d2dc5c6493464> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/710543EA-CD06-4A04-8D8D-3214C0C5C4F6/WeatherIt.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib
```

Comment: What are some of the first thing your app does after it launches? Also your crash report is not symbolicated correctly. This just shows memory addresses and a properly symbolicated crash report will have method names and classes.

Comment: I think I figured it out. I think it is an issue with the network connection. I hadn't tested it before when the app didn't have internet. I'm guessing that the reviewer started testing no internet with the iPad Air 2 first. I will post more when I find out.